# Block internet access to my client systems in my LAN

Tags: internet, client

i have installed ubuntu 12.04 server in hp server hardware with 2 NICs.  I have configured internet using NAT and is working fine. 
My problem is, i want to block some system from internet only.  Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the requests of your client PCs to wild using iptables.

> sudo iptables -A INPUT -s `client_ip` -p tcp --dport `port_number` -j ACCEPT

For port_number specify a port that you can't use to access Internet (123 maybe?)